# Zero divisor of a graded piece

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R=\bigoplus R_d=\bigoplus \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]_d$. Suppose $I=(p_1,\dots,p_k)$ is an ideal generated in $R_d$ and $I_d\cdot R_d\neq R_{2d}$. Is it true that if an element $p\in R_d$ is such that $p\cdot R_d\subset I\cdot R_d$, then also $p\in I$?
Equivalently, considering $L=\bigoplus (R/I)_d $, then if $[p]\in (R/I)_d$ satisfies $[ph]=[0
]$ for every $h\in R_d$, then $[p]=0$?

I am convinced to be true, but I cannot manage to find proof. It looks to me like some result that could be written in a book in even more general terms. If you have any references or ideas on how to prove I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It is always the case that $I\cdot R_d\neq R_{2d}$, as $I$ always contains elements of degree $>d$. Do you maybe mean $I_d\cdot R_d\neq R_{2d}$?

Comment: Yes, I meant the degree piece $2d$ of $I\cdot R_d$ is not equal to $R_{2d}$. I will edit it to make more clear, thanks!

Comment: By looking at the vanishing set we get that $V(p)\cup V(q)\supseteq V(I)$ for all $q\in R_d$, which implies $V(p)\supseteq V(I)$. So we obtain that there exists $n>0$ with $p^n\in I$, but I don't see yet how to get to $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: let $n=4, d=6, R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w], I=(x^4y^2, x^5y, x^4yz, x^4zw, x^4w^2), p=x^4yw\notin I.$ Then $x^3y^9\notin I_6R_6$ so that $I_6R_6\neq R_{12}$. We have $xp, yp, zp, wp\in I$ and $pR_6\subset I.$